# List dropdown with logged in user

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list

I am trying to make a field in a list autopopulate with the signed in user. I tried the Lookup field and it gives me a choice but it doesn't change based on which user is logged in. Any ideas how I get that to work?
For instance:

Initiated by: (should autopopulate currently logged in user)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2013 you can do this by adding a JavaScript to the New form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var loginName = "";
var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;

GetCurrentUser();

function GetCurrentUser() {

var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";    
var requestHeaders = { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" };

$.ajax({
  url : requestUri,
  contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",
  headers : requestHeaders,
  success : onSuccess,
  error : onError
  });
}

function onSuccess(data, request) {
    var loginName = data.d.Title;
    //set the value to the field "LogedInUser" in the new form
    $('input[title="LogedInUser"]').val(loginName);    
}

function onError(error) {
  alert(error);
}

</script>
```